# Using jQuery's AJAX To Send JSON To A PHP File

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

consider:
I've collected form data and want to make a JSON object. then send that object to php, which is going to decode it, using json_decode().
How is that possible?

A,B,C,D are form data.

```
var formData = [{"task": A , "due_time": due_B, "due_date" : C , "priority": D}];

$.ajax({url: someplace.php , type: "post" , data: formData});
```

**In PHP**: I want to check

```
if isset($_POST['formData']){ $data = json_decode($_POST['formData'])}
```

Comment: I wouldn't build the JSON by yourself. Use ` JSON.stringify`.

Comment: you should add `dataType: 'json'` within `$.ajax({....})`

Answer (score 0):

Create valid JS object:

```
[jQuery]
var obj = {task: "A", due_time: due_b, /*...*/};

$.ajax({
   url: '#',
   type: 'post',
   data: obj
});
```

All sent values are located in `$_POST` global.

```
[PHP]
if (isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'A') {
    $startApocalypse = true;
}
```